# Can we use Ad Mob for PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

can we use Ad Mob with phonegap app, Is there any API for Ad Mob implements with phonegap for Android, Windows Phone and iPhone  ?

Comment: sure you can,
Just check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530055/any-woking-admob-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-android

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply but what we can do for Windows phone  and iPhone

Comment: for iPhone you can implement it also, check this link: http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/05/cordova-phonegap-and-admob-together-ios.html

Comment: honestly i didn't look for windows mobile yet, but for sure there is a way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am finding ad-mob for windows phone.
code below presents default XAML created by PhoneGap template for WP7, modified to display AdMob banner at the bottom of a mobile app.

```
<grid x:name="LayoutRoot" background="Transparent" horizontalalignment="Stretch">
<grid.rowdefinitions>
   <rowdefinition height="*"></rowdefinition>
   <rowdefinition height="75"></rowdefinition> <!-- Extra grid row for AdMob -->
</grid.rowdefinitions>

<!-- Original container displaying your HTML -->
<my:cordovaview grid.row="0" horizontalalignment="Stretch" margin="0,0,0,0" x:name="CordovaView" verticalalignment="Stretch">
</my:cordovaview>

<!-- Our AdMob banner: -->
<google:bannerad grid.row="1" adunitid="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID" xmlns:google="clr-namespace:Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF;assembly=Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7">
</google:bannerad>
```

lets check for additional details http://fczaja.blogspot.in/2012/09/admob-ads-in-phonegap-apps.html